# Outer join in Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
    $queryBuilder
        ->add('select', 't.id, u.name, t.date, t.type, t.machineNumber, t.area, ua.id AS uaid')
        ->add('from', 'Model:Task t')
        ->join('t.user', 'u')
        ->join('t.approvedUser', 'ua')
        ->setFirstResult($start)
        ->setMaxResults($length);
```

There is a field called `approved_user_id` in the "Tasks" table. In the model it is `approvedUser` - an association to a `User` object.

It's okay for a task to be unapproved (approved_user_id = NULL). If it's been approved, then a user id will be stored in there of the user who approved it.

What I want is to return all records from Tasks table using the query above.

But currently, it only returns records where approvedUser is not null (due to the inner join)

How can I return all records, such that I get ua.id as an integer (the user id of the user who approved the task) in the cases where the task is approved and ua.id as null in the cases where the task is unapproved?

Comment: I'm confused. DQL appears to support leftjoin, so what's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't support left outer join, so when I join it only includes records where there is a non-null `approvedUser` - whereas I want all results, including those where `approvedUser` is null. It's okay - in the end I worked around it by adding IDENTITY to the `approvedUser`, that did the trick for me.

Comment: Well a left join do select the null relations! Are you sure your relation is declared as nullable in your entity?